# What does reset actually mean in Tensorflow 2 dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

I'm following tensorflow 2 Keras [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/keras/training_and_evaluation). My model looks like this:

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((np.array([_my_cus_func(i) for i in X_train]), y_train))
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(lambda vals,lab: _process_tensors(vals,lab), num_parallel_calls=4)
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(64,drop_remainder=True)
train_dataset = train_dataset.prefetch(1)
model=get_compiled_model()
model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=100)
```

The documentation says

> Note that the Dataset is reset at the end of each epoch, so it can be
>   reused of the next epoch.
>
> If you want to run training only on a specific number of batches from
>   this Dataset, you can pass the steps_per_epoch argument, which
>   specifies how many training steps the model should run using this
>   Dataset before moving on to the next epoch.
>
> If you do this, the dataset is not reset at the end of each epoch,
>   instead we just keep drawing the next batches. The dataset will
>   eventually run out of data (unless it is an infinitely-looping
>   dataset).

What does the reset actually mean? Will tensorflow read data from tensor slices after every epoch? or it only reshuffles and runs `map` function? I want tensorflow to read data from numpy after epoch and run `_my_cus_func`. I can rather pass `_my_cus_func` on `dataset map or apply api`, but I'm more comfortable in doing this on python list or numpy array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, reset means start iterating over dataset from scratch. In your particular case, code lacks `repeat()` function. So, if you specify `steps_per_epoch` parameter like this

```
model.fit(train_dataset, steps_per_epoch=N, epochs=100)
```

It will iterate over the dataset for N steps, if N is less than actual number of examples, it will terminate training. If N is larger, it will finish one epoch, but still terminates when runs out of data . If you add repeat,

```
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10000).repeat()
```

It will start new cycle over dataset when actual number of examples is reached, not when new epoch starts.

Comment: Thanks. Ideally, `N` should be `sample size/batch size` right?

Comment: Exactly, total number of samples / batch size